# jQuery take number from string and append html with extracted number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery which adds a small span after the message icon to allow a small notification bubble to show, but using the method below, if a user gets more than 5 messages, it doesnt show. Technically a user could have an unlimited number of message sent to them, but rather than copy and paste this a hundred times...
What I would like to do is copy the "Messages (1 new)" string, take the number out of the string as "1" and then append a span like this... "1

```
jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a:contains("Messages (1 new)")').append( "<span>1</span>" );
jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a:contains("Messages (2 new)")').append( "<span>2</span>" );
jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a:contains("Messages (3 new)")').append( "<span>3</span>" );
jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a:contains("Messages (4 new)")').append( "<span>4</span>" );
jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a:contains("Messages (5 new)")').append( "<span>5</span>" );
```

[image]

heres the html, but its not easy to change as its generated by a cms module.

```
<ul>
  <li class="first"><a href="/messages/new">Write new message</a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="/messages">Messages (2 new)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How about a `for` loop?

Comment: What about 0 new messages?

Comment: When theres no messages, no notification bubble needs to show. Please see the image I have included as an example of the message notification.

Comment: please share your html. and can you customize your html?

Comment: is that jQuery code the only code you have controlling the notifications? and as Dan mentioned, share your html as well. It helps with the context of the problem when trying to think it out

Comment: How does it know wether its 1,2,3 messages? you clearly haven't shown all your code...lets see it.

Comment: Updated the question with the html. How its generated isnt the issue here. The jQuery currently works just fine, im looking for a way to write it where i dont have to copy and paste for every possible number of messages

Comment: Ideally just to be pointed in the right direction for terminology would help, not sure what i should be googling to find an answer myself. Why all the downvotes? This place is brutal!

Comment: it's not a great question. the title is misleading, you're not trying to shorten *jQuery*, you're trying to inspect HTML for a number and then create some more HTML based on that number

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and take the [tour] if you're not sure why you're being downvoted. Especially read the bit about creating a [mcve].

Comment: OK, i will read up on that. Ive updated the question, but its hardly minimal and complete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [.append( function )](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) like in:

```js
jQuery('li.last a').append(function(i, h) {
  var n = h.match(/^\D*(\d)\D*$/);
  return (n == null) ? null :  $('<span>', {text: n[1]});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="/messages/new">Write new message</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/messages">Messages (2 new)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but im getting... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: @Collins Sorry, Updated

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

If no new messages means don't show a notification bubble I would just do the following (substring matching + innerHTML + replace):

```
var el = jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last'),
    r = new RegExp("[^d]", g);


el.find("a:contains("Messages (")').append( "<span>" + el.find("a").html().replace(r, "") + "</span>" )
```

I am assuming the pattern will hold for n messages.

Answer (score 1):

Is there no other way of getting the number of messages other than inspecting the HTML? If so, I would look at that first. Otherwise, you could do this:

```
var $elem = jQuery('#block-privatemsg-privatemsg-menu .content li.last a');
var text = $elem.text();
var matches = text.match('/d+/');
if (matches && matches.length) {
    $elem.append('<span>' + matches[0] + '</span>');
}
```

Kinda messy but should work.